# Is PDO::lastInsertId reliable with very rapid inserts?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, yii

I'm using the Yii PHP framework which has a function PDO::lastInsertId that's apparently just an implementation of PDO::lastInsertId. If my application has very rapid inserts from possibly thousands of simultaneous users, will this function be reliable to get the Auto-incremented row ID of the data I just inserted?

I need to get the id of the row I just inserted to do a bit of work after the insert itself, but want to make sure that if the insert rate is very high, it wont cause inconsistent results.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

yes, of course, no worries about that, but you've to make sure to ask the lastInsertId just after the insert query. No other query should be executed on that connection in the meantime, each PHP process must have a separate connection.

Also if you think that a table is going to have hundreds or thousands of insert per second, consider to not use indexes or use the minimum amount of indexes. In case of MySQL favour MyISAM tables.

Comment: The lastInsertId() call is made immediately following the insert query, my worry was about the other simultaneous users. Do PHP processes have separate connections by default? (I guess most specifically within yii?). Thanks for getting back to me.

Comment: > Do PHP processes have separate connections by default? Yes.

Comment: +1 very good answear. Maybe removing temporarely the indexes might give more insertion speed (I guess).

Comment: I'm keeping the indexes to a minimum, at this point I only have 2 on this table, and both are required. I'm using InnoDB though. Inserts and reads are both very frequent, so the row level locking is more attractive than the table level. Thanks again to @stivlo.